# Custom close button in frameless window (ElectronJS)

Tags: html, node.js, electron

I created a frameless button, I want to have a close and minimize button, I created a button but how do I make window close after it's clicked? I want the script to be in separated file from `index.js` as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ipc via ipcrenderer: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ipcMain and ipcRenderer

in the main.js

```
ipcMain.on("CLOSE-APP", (event) => {
    applicationWindow.close();//applicationWindow is global variable for browser window
});
ipcMain.on("MINIMIZE-APP", (event) => {
    applicationWindow.minimize();//applicationWindow is global variable for browser window
});
ipcMain.on("MAXIMIZE-APP", (event) => {
    applicationWindow.maximize();//applicationWindow is global variable for browser window
});
```

in the renderer.js

```
$('#close-btn').on('click', () => {
   ipcRenderer.send("CLOSE-APP");
});
$('#minimize-btn').on('click', () => {
   ipcRenderer.send("MINIMIZE-APP");
});
$('#maximize-btn').on('click', () => {
   ipcRenderer.send("MAXIMIZE-APP");
});
```

In addition to these, you can use it in the whole application by using a preload script by defining it in only 1 place.